# Formatting json array in order to add label to values in Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list, dictionary

i'm writing a python script in order to extract some data from a device and i need to formatting my json output.
Now i have this output (example):

```
[
    [
        "Environment",
        "ok"
    ],
    [
        "Memory",
        "ok"
    ]
]
```

But i want to add labels in order to call values, like this example:

```
[
    [
        {"component":"Environment",
        "status":"ok"}
    ],
    [
        {"component":"Memory",
        "status":"ok"}
    ]
]
```

I'm trying to search online, but i cannot find what i'm searching. It is possibile?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
intermediate_output = [
    [
        "Environment",
        "ok"
    ],
    [
        "Memory",
        "ok"
    ]
]

final_output = [[{"component": x[0], "status": x[1]}] for x in intermediate_output]

print(final_output)
```

Output :

```
[[{'component': 'Environment', 'status': 'ok'}], [{'component': 'Memory', 'status': 'ok'}]]
```

EDIT :

Now if you want list of all components, before you move forward, I'd suggest you strip your nested list and make it a plain list.

```
>>> striped_list = [list1[0] for list1 in final_output]
>>> striped_list

[{'component': 'Environment', 'status': 'ok'}, {'component': 'Memory', 'status': 'ok'}]
```

Now, use list comprehension...

```
>>> list_of_components = [item['component'] for item in striped_list]
>>> list_of_components

['Environment', 'Memory']
```

**For status of a particular component, again you could use for loops or list comprehensions.**

```
>>> my_component = "Environment" # we have to find status of this component

>>> my_component_status = [item['status'] for item in striped_list if item['component'] == my_component]

>>> my_component_status

['ok']
```

Excellent documentation for understanding list comprehension

https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python

Cheers!!

Comment: thanks a lot. it works! but i've two more question. Now my json is formatted like this:
[
    [
        {
            "status": "ok",
            "component": "Environment"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "status": "ok",
            "component": "Memory"
        }
    ]
]

why status is the first element?
If i want to have a list of all components, what's the command to launch?
If i want to have the status of a single component, what's the command to launch?
I ask because i've tried with some print commands without luck.

Comment: @maures before I could answer your questions, can you share the screenshot of the code where you're are getting status as the first element?

Comment: i've just a json array like that you've seen on my main question.

Comment: @maures I have run the same code multiple times and on different machines, and there is no way you would receive status as the first ellement,

Comment: that's not a problem. can you answer me about other question please?

Comment: @maures Updated my answer to accommodate new questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Using *List comprehension*.

```
a= [['Environment', 'ok'], ['Memory', 'ok']]
[{'component':x,'status':y} for x,y in a ]
```

---

output

```
[{'component': 'Environment', 'status': 'ok'},
 {'component': 'Memory', 'status': 'ok'}]
```